# retrieve current users id from mysql database to use in new table using visual basic 2008

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim AM As String = "8:01:00 AM"
    Dim remarks As String
    
    If LblTime.Text >= AM Then
        remarks = "LATE"
    Else
        remarks = "ON TIME"

    End If
    Try
        With com
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "SELECT count(*) Searchflag from employees_records where id_no='" & Txtid.Text & "' and date like '" & LblDate.Text & "';"
        End With
     
        
        sql = "INSERT INTO attendance (id_no, am_in, am_remarks, date) VALUES (@id_no, @am_in, @am_remarks, @date)"
        com.Connection = con
        com.CommandText = sql

        com.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@id_no", Txtid.Text))
        com.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@am_in", LblTime.Text))
        com.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@am_remarks", remarks))
        com.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@date", LblDate.Text))


        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If remarks = "LATE" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Hurry up your Late")
        ElseIf remarks = "ON TIME" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Very good you come on time!")
        End If




    Catch ex As Exception

      
    End Try

End Sub
```

I can't retrieve the `id_no` from another table mysql is my database

Comment: You need to be way more specific than `"I can't retrieve the id_no"`.

Comment: id is string or integer

Comment: Where is stored this id_no that you want to retrieve? Your code above doesn't retrieve any id_no field instead uses a textbox as value to insert an id_no in a table. So you already know this value.

Comment: id_no stored in another table which is in the employees_records

Comment: @ChrisGee when you want to notify someone of your comment add the `at sign` and select its name. In this way a comment icon is displayed on destination user.

Comment: So you want to retrieve the id_no from the table employees, but this requires that you have some key to apply for the WHERE clause on this table (the employees secuity number, the account/password keys or something else) How do you identify your employee record?

Comment: by  their name and id number

Comment: @Steve im very sorry for the very late reply

Answer (score 0):

Write This Way::

```
Dim AM As String = "8:01:00 AM"
Dim remarks As String

If LblTime.Text >= AM Then
    remarks = "LATE"
Else
    remarks = "ON TIME"

End If
Try
    With com
        .Connection = con
        .CommandText = "SELECT count(*) Searchflag from employees_records where id_no=" & val(Txtid.Text) & " and date like '" & LblDate.Text & "';"
    End With


    sql = "INSERT INTO attendance (id_no, am_in, am_remarks, date) VALUES (@id_no, @am_in, @am_remarks, @date)"
    com.Connection = con
    com.CommandText = sql

    com.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@id_no", Txtid.Text))
    com.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@am_in", LblTime.Text))
    com.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@am_remarks", remarks))
    com.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@date", LblDate.Text))


    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If remarks = "LATE" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Hurry up your Late")
    ElseIf remarks = "ON TIME" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Very good you come on time!")
    End If




Catch ex As Exception


End Try
```

End Sub